# cellForItemAtIndexPath is Changing Multiple Cells When Should Change One

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I may be not understanding the reusing of cells behaviour by the UICollectionView but can someone tell me why two cells are having their properties changed in cellForItemAtIndexPath when it should just be the one cell.

Here's my code.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  PhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (PhotoCollectionViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (![[self.userPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@""]){
    NSString *photoUrl = [self.userPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: photoUrl];
    NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
   [cell.photoImageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

      cell.photoImageView.image = image;
      cell.photoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0f,100.0f);
      cell.photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

      [cell.deleteImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(-4.0f,-4.0f,28.0f,28.0f)];
      cell.deleteImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.deleteImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
      [cell.deleteImageView setAlpha:0.8f];
      cell.deleteImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
      cell.deleteImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }];
  }else{
    cell.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"];
    cell.photoImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    cell.photoImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    NSLog(@"setting alpha & hiding delete");
    cell.photoImageView.alpha = 0.4f;
    [cell.deleteImageView setHidden:YES];
  }
```

The code in the else part is being executed on cells 2 and 6 for example when it should just be 6. Although the logging says it's just executed on 6

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to check: does cell 2 appear OK at first, and only look like cell 6 when you scroll back up?

Comment: Yes. It's fine then seems to be redrawn from a recycled cell (the modified one) when I scroll.

Comment: Have you implemented `prepareForReuse` in your  `PhotoCollectionViewCell` class?  It is called by the collection view when it reuses a cell, and is your opportunity to reset everything.  Looking at your code, that might be view frames/layers/alphas/hidden... etc.

Comment: A reused cell must be somehow "cleansed", either in `prepareForReuse` or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Otherwise it will continue to display "old" data.